# ms access 2010 not getting data when giving the condition year to year

Tags: date, ms-access-2010

I have a weird issue with MS ACCESS 2010.
I have a table RawData with column `TaskDate` (format is Memo). When I use the below query I am getting the desired data,

```
`select * from RawData where TaskDate between '01/01/2012' and '12/31/2012'`
```

But when I use the below query I am not getting any data:

```
select * from RawData where TaskDate between '01/01/2012' and '01/01/2013'
```

I don't understand the problem as the data comparison was not happening with this 'Year' value. Please help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh dude. You realize how bad that is? "No idea how to use a database" style, sadly. Time for reading documentation on data types.

Ok, here we go:

> TaskDate (format is Memo)

Yes, and however did that should be publicly flogged. First, this is a TEXT field, second it is for LONG texts which dates never are. Fail on two levels.

If the format is Memo it is text, so "between" compares texts.

> '01/01/2012' and '12/31/2012'`

that is left to right.

i.e. first letter 0 or 1, second letter 1 or 2, 4th letter between 0 and 3, 5th letter between 1 and 1. Goes on...

> '01/01/2012' and '01/01/2013'

that would mean basically everything of 01/01 on 2012 and 2013 ONLY. Assuming this is a holiday, without tasks - well, no data. Why? because any other date fails. The first characters have to match '01/01/201'.

If you would like do do that properly, you can:

- Change the formatting of dates to make sense as text. THat is ISO norm: 2012-01-01 to 2012-12-31. That means they order correct as they go left to right.
- Better: Dump the stupid idea to use Memo for dates

Read

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/tips-for-choosing-field-types-in-access-2010.html

then use Date/Time as field type, and magically Access will not try to compare texts (which is has no clue what they mean internally, so it can not apply the semantics of dates to them) and compare real dates.

Right now you made sure there is no "date" comparison. It is pure stupid little string, left to right, character by character, no additional logic.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I am really new to this thing, so you might find my post very novice.. I have changed the format and used the below query for getting the results....... select * from RawData where TaskDate between #1/1/2012# and #1/1/2013#.  Got the results now